# I need to get array of bytes from image

Tags: objective-c, encoding, nsmutablearray, arrays

I'm trying to get a byte array containing the bytes of an image, like this:

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image" ofType:@"png"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
unsigned char *bytesArray = data.bytes;
NSUInteger lengthOfBytesArray = data.length;
```

Next, I try to copy these values into an array.

```
    if (data.length>0)
    {
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:data.length];
        for (int i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
            unsigned char byteFromArray = bytesArray[i];
            [array addObject:[NSValue valueWithBytes:&byteFromArray objCType:@encode(unsigned char)]];

        }
    }
```

Finally in debug I received array of empty objects. They have memory address but don't have a value (NSConcreateValue type). Also in debug area I've checked `byteFromArray` and it is a `(unsigned char)'P'.  Did I choose the wrong way to get a byte array from image, or is my code wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this

```
    for (int i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
        unsigned char byteFromArray = bytesArray[i];
        [array addObject:[NSValue valueWithBytes:&byteFromArray objCType:@encode(unsigned char)]];
    }
```

with this

```
    for (int i = 0; i<data.length; i++) 
        [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedChar:bytesArray[i]]];
```

Also, I suggest adding an NSLog to display the data.length just to see how many elements are being added to the array.